# How to add FieldMask of unknown field '21' in Java

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, dialogflow-es

I'm using dialogflow-es with Java library(v2).

And I found that Intent object doesn't have the method of "Set this intent as end of conversation".

I found that field's name of 'end of conversation' is `21`, and value is `1`.

So, I created the `UnknownFieldSet` and `FieldMask` with `.addPaths("unknown_fields")`.

But after update intent, nothing was changed.

When I remove `.setFieldMask(FieldMask fieldMask)` from update intent, value was changed.

How can I change unknown field `21` with `FieldMask`?

```
UnknownFieldSet unknownFieldSet = UnknownFieldSet.newBuilder()
        .addField(21, Field.newBuilder().addVarint(1).build())
        .build();

FieldMask updateFieldMask = FieldMask.newBuilder()
        .addPaths("unknown_fields")
        .build();

Intent updateIntent = Intent.newBuilder()
        .setName(newIntent.getName())
        .setUnknownFields(unknownFieldSet)
        .build();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sound like you're looking for [FieldMaskUtil.merge](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/util/FieldMaskUtil.html#merge-com.google.protobuf.FieldMask-com.google.protobuf.Message-com.google.protobuf.Message.Builder-) and [FieldMaskUtil.fromFieldNumbers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/util/FieldMaskUtil.html#fromFieldNumbers-java.lang.Class-int...-).

If that doesn't work, then what you're doing may just be impossible -- to do it with `FieldMask` instead of with field numbers directly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I've tried your suggestion, but it shows me IllegalArgumentException.
Maybe it can't be modified as you say.

Comment: I've found that v2 doesn't support endInteraction value... So, I changed dialogflow.v2 to dialogflow.v2beta1. Now I can use setEndInteraction(boolean).